# What was the meaning behind the turbine and the fizzy lifting drink?

Tags: willy-wonka, charlie-and-the-chocolate-factory, roald-dahl

In [*Willy Wonka and the Chocolate Factory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willy_Wonka_%26_the_Chocolate_Factory) (the 1971 musical), each of the children was removed from the competition by them not being able to resist their character flaws.

Augustus is sucked through a chocolate extraction pipe system and sent to the Fudge Room, having fallen into a chocolate river from which he was trying to drink. Violet transforms into a giant blueberry after trying an experimental piece of Three-Course-Dinner Gum. Veruca is rejected as a "bad egg" and falls down a garbage chute in the Chocolate Golden Egg Sorting Room. Mike is shrunken to only a few inches in height after being transmitted by "Wonkavision", a broadcasting technology that can send objects through television instead of pictures.

What did the fizzy lifting drink represent to Charlie?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I always interpreted it as Charlie's desire for bigger and better things. Flying in dreams often represents being on top of things, or in control. That was something Charlie never had growing up. He was always poor and felt like he had a poor lot in life.

Flying was a representation of him rising above all that. But without restraint, humility and control, he would have died in the turbine. With great power comes great responsibility. Freedom without constraint leads to a bad end.

This ties in with Wonka's conversation later. Charlie did something no one else had: he showed that he wasn't corruptible by greed; he showed remorse for what he had done. That was what earned him the prize.